# troubles implementing sudo authentication using webhooks

Tags: python, linux, websocket

I am trying to build a multitool of communication between client and server, but I run into an issue while trying to communicate anything that requires authentication:

```
if decision == "1":
        mySocket.sendto(b'sht',(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))
        passwd = input("""
        
        the choice requires sudo, please enter the password for sudo:

        """)

        mySocket.sendto(passwd ,(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))
```

this is the portion of the code in question, using the vanilla 'socket' package I communicate sht, which means shutdown. but I run into

> `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

can someone please explain? it should work flawlessly

I tried having different ways of storing the password locally on the server, but obviously I compromise security this way.

Comment: It seems you need to convert `passwd` to bytes.